# World of Warcraft API SetPoint API "Couldn't find region named '(null)'"

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I wanted to fix a lua error in my TukUI AddOn `GameTooltip:SetPoint(): Couldn't find region named '(null)'`. It is happening when two of my AddOns are turned on: TukUI (modded) and LKAnnounce. If I turn off LKAnnounce, the error goes away. I read that you can't simply debug lua code in WoW because you might get banned while attaching a debugger. The only thing I can think of is using `print` calls. It's a bit weird but that error message disappears if I reload my UI (/reload). May it be related to the AddOn loading sequence?

My goal is to identify the problem myself and fix it. I found that API here: https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/API_Region_SetPoint

Link for the AddOns: https://easyupload.io/t90ozw (3.3.5)

Result from the prints:

```
print(self) // nil
print(TukuiDB) // table: 1BDD81D0
```

This is the error message:

```
Message: Interface\AddOns\Tukui\datatext\system.lua:98: GameTooltip:SetPoint(): Couldn't find region named '(null)'
Time: 01/30/20 11:50:59
Count: 1
Stack: [C]: in function `SetPoint'
Interface\AddOns\Tukui\datatext\system.lua:98: in function <Interface\AddOns\Tukui\datatext\system.lua:94>

Locals: (*temporary) = GameTooltip {
 updateTooltip = 0.12099999543279
 SetInventoryItem = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\GearScoreLite\GearScoreLite.lua:226
 0 = <userdata>
 comparing = false
 shoppingTooltips = <table> {
 }
}
(*temporary) = "BOTTOM"
(*temporary) = <table> {
 ZOOMED_ICON_SMALL = ":12:12:0:0:64:64:4:60:4:60"
 RemoveHealer = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2650
 ratio_to_hex_color = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:14
 RemoveFromAssignments = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3405
 stuns = <table> {
 }
 HandleCombatMessage = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3491
 RemoveRotationSelect = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2505
 ReleaseUID = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2361
 UpdateRaidRoster = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2814
 debug = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3
 dec_to_hex_color = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:21
 message = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:45
 Announce_Slows = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2715
 AddHealer = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2616
 ValkyrTimeout = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3635
 CheckWipe = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2963
 AnnounceInfests = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2576
 possible_infests = <table> {
 }
 possible_aoe_stuns = <table> {
 }
 slows = <table> {
 }
 AddInfest = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2513
 shapes_sets = <table> {
 }
 StartEncounter = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2969
 ChatUpdate = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:299
 possible_stuns = <table> {
 }
 GetDefaultOptions = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:4142
 CheckInfestWasted = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2470
 PlagueExpired = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3765
 aoe_slows = <table> {
 }
 FlashScreen = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2447
 printraid = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:49
 EndEncounter = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2988
 Set_Assignment = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2492
 pad = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:35
 Announce_Trap_Hits = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3770
 LeftRaid = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3004
 AnnounceDPS = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2552
 DefaultOptions = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:4339
 DefaultAssignments = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:4138
 GetDefaultAssignments = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:4125
 Handle_Valks = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3819
 RemoveRole = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3200
 AnnounceHealingAssignment = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3476
 Calculate_Plagues = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:3641
 UpdateTarget = <function> defined @Interface\AddOns\LKAnnounce\LKAnnounce.lua:2887
 Get_Assignment = <function>
```

AddOns\Tukui\datatext\system.lua

```lua
Stat:SetScript("OnEnter", function()
    if not InCombatLockdown() then
        GameTooltip:SetOwner(this, "ANCHOR_TOP", 0, TukuiDB.Scale(6));
        GameTooltip:ClearAllPoints()
        GameTooltip:SetPoint("BOTTOM", self, "TOP", 0, TukuiDB.mult) --94 line

        print(self) --nil
        print(TukuiDB) --table: 1BDD81D0

        GameTooltip:ClearLines()
        GameTooltip:AddDoubleLine(tukuilocal.datatext_totalmemusage,formatMem(Total), 0.69, 0.31, 0.31,0.84, 0.75, 0.65)
        GameTooltip:AddLine(" ")
        for i = 1, #Memory do
            if Memory[i][3] then 
                local red = Memory[i][2]/Total*2
                local green = 1 - red
                GameTooltip:AddDoubleLine(Memory[i][1], formatMem(Memory[i][2], false), 1, 1, 1, red, green+1, 0)                       
            end
        end
        GameTooltip:Show()
    end
end)
```

I also read this article: https://www.wowinterface.com/portal.php?id=460&a=faq&faqid=486 and I tried BugSack and BugGrabber in order to identify the problem. It says the following:

```
1. 1x Tukui-1.44\datatext\system.lua:98: GameTooltip:SetPoint(): Couldn't find region named '(null)'
Tukui-1.44\datatext\system.lua:98: in function <Tukui\datatext\system.lua:94>

Locals:
formatMem = <function> @ Tukui\datatext\system.lua:16:
Total = 11453.549804688
Memory = <table> {
 1 = <table> {}
 2 = <table> {}
...
```

system.lua from line 16 to line 40:

```
local function formatMem(memory, color)
    if color then
        statColor = { "|cff"..colorme, "|r" }
    else
        statColor = { "", "" }
    end

    local mult = 10^1
    if memory > 999 then
        local mem = floor((memory/1024) * mult + 0.5) / mult
        if mem % 1 == 0 then
            return mem..string.format(".0 %smb%s", unpack(statColor))
        else
            return mem..string.format(" %smb%s", unpack(statColor))
        end
    else
        local mem = floor(memory * mult + 0.5) / mult
            if mem % 1 == 0 then
                return mem..string.format(".0 %skb%s", unpack(statColor))
            else
                return mem..string.format(" %skb%s", unpack(statColor))
            end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** GameTooltip:SetPoint() is protected since WoW 8.2 to prevent cheating.

**Details:** This addon was trying to override the behaviour of GameTooltip:SetOwner(), present just two lines earlier, by manually repositioning the anchor to someplace else.  It did this by clearing all points (line 93) and manually assigning a point (line 94).

**Assumption:** The SetPoint command was originally done correctly prior to WoW 8.2, meaning that TukuiDB.mult is intended to be a numeric y-offset for the tooltip.

**Solution:** Replace lines 92 to 94 with a single command.

```
GameTooltip:SetOwner(self, "ANCHOR_TOP", 0, TukuiDB.mult)
```

References:

- [Wowpedia](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GameTooltip_SetOwner)
- Kaivax, 19 Jun 19, [UI Changes in Rise of Azshara](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/wow/t/ui-changes-in-rise-of-azshara/202487)

Comment: did you mean that? https://i.imgur.com/cRUvbj1.png It gave a new error: `Message: Interface\AddOns\Tukui\datatext\system.lua:98: attempt to index global 'TukUIDB' (a nil value)`. Also the patch version is 3.3.5.

Comment: I made a mistake, fixed above.  TukUIDB should be TukuiDB.  Also, this is SetOwner().  I linked the right command on Wowpedia, but accidentally wrote it wrong in the answer.  lol